# How to run Jetpack from localhost?

Tags: plugins, localhost, plugin-jetpack

I just installed the jetpack plugin on my localhost version of WordPress 4.2.2 however after activating it—when I click on 'Connect to Wordpress.com', I get the following error:

[image]

> Your website needs to be publicly accessible to use Jetpack: site_inaccessible Error Details: The Jetpack server was unable to communicate with your site `http://wordpress.local` [IXR -32300: transport error: http_request_failed Couldn't resolve host 'wordpress.local']

Is there any way to work around this running on localhost?

Comment: I prefer to do it via [one-line plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/144317/26350) so I don't have to open `wp-config.php` to support this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jetpack Running Locally](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42352/jetpack-running-locally)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this to your `wp-config.php`:

```
const JETPACK_DEV_DEBUG = TRUE;
```

This makes it possible to use features on localhost that don’t require a connection to wordpress.com. See the [announcement post on jetpack.me](http://jetpack.me/2013/03/28/jetpack-dev-mode-release/) for the background.

For your own plugins, learn that lesson: Do not rely on working outgoing connections. Respect your users privacy, and explain in clear words why such a connection is necessary, what data will be sent, and how to work with the plugin when the connection fails. In other words: Don’t do it the Jetpack way.

Comment: Thanks I tried this, I activated `contact forms` and I don't see any button on the new Page or new Posts? Am I missing something?

Comment: The button vanishes when you set the constant, but is there when you don’t?

Comment: I don't see the button at all after activating the contact form. Using the default 2015 theme.

Comment: When I activate it on `wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack_modules` I get the button.

Comment: It's activated for me (when I click on JetPack Settings I can see it's showing as active) the contact form yet, it's not appearing when I edit a page or create a new page?

Comment: Enable the [debug mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), and look also into your JavaScript console (`Ctrl + Shift + i`) for errors.

Comment: Ok turned on debug and checked the console for errors, I did get a block error then turned off adblock and ublock and no more errors, yet it still doesn't appear when creating a new page or editing a page?

Comment: That’s a separate problem then. Ask a new question, explain there what you have done already to debug it.

Comment: +999999999 for `Don't do it the Jetpack way`. What an obnoxious plugin.

Comment: Use the following as per their documentation => define( 'JETPACK_DEV_DEBUG', true );   https://jetpack.com/support/development-mode/

Comment: @AndrewSchultz That's exactly the same. `define()` is just the old way to declare the constant.